# Mapcache support for multiple formats

Tags: png, mapcache

I'm wondering if there's any other way in map cache to support multiple formats (png and jpeg for example) than to create a new tile set?

For example if I have a WMS 'source' called `topo2_wms` (that supports png and jpeg), and a tile set called `topo2cache`.

What's the best ways to create tiles in both png and jpeg?

Is it really necessary to create 2 tile sets, one called `topo2cache_png` and one `topo2cache_jpeg`?